# DIFFICULT SQL issue

Tags: sql, oracle

Bear in mind this needs to be done in SQL - not PL/SQL, no while loops in play here.

I need to go from a single row with an amount, to multiple rows with the amount spread out. Here's the details;

I have a rule that awards in-lieu hours when an employee is short for a period. However, this rule awards ALL the hours on the last day of the period, and the client wants it spread out 8 hrs/day.

For example, if an EE is short 25 hours - the existing rule will award that 25 hours on the last day of the period. Client wants 8 hours on last day, 8 hours on 2nd last day, 8 hrs on 3rd last day, 1 hr on 4th last day.

My SQL is great, but I'm drawing a blank on this one. Any suggestions? Again, no PL/SQL or while loops allowed, has to be done in SQL (Oracle).

Sample data

Start with this;

```
**ID Date        Amount**
1  09/30/2013  25
```

Need to end up with this;

```
**ID Date        Amount**
1  09/30/2013  8
1  09/29/2013  8
1  09/28/2013  8
1  09/27/2013  1
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and the expected output. Ideally as an example on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: This site just doesn't work like that. You cannot write what you need and wait for some code, that looks like ordering.

Comment: Soon expected: 'How not to write good questions. The art of mingling.' by ps_guru.      Seriously: you need to provided more info, as per previous comments.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I've edited the original question to provide sample data/expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a table with all the possible days, you could then cross-join to that.  Maybe that table has an actual date, but it also has a day number on each row: 1, 2, 3, 4... where that is the order in which you want to allocate the hours: i.e. 8 hours to day #1, any remaining (but max 8) to day # 2, and so on.

For any particular day_num, the expression ( (day_num - 1) * 8 ) will give you the max. hours that could be allocated already. Only if the employee has hours over this, does this particular day get an allocation. Also, the allocation has to be limited to 8.

The SQL would look something like below. ([See this SQL fiddle for schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76dc8/4))

```
select emp_id, total_hours, day_num,
       case 
          when total_hours - ((day_num-1) * 8) > 8 then 8
          when total_hours - ((day_num-1) * 8) < 0 then 0
          else total_hours - ((day_num-1) * 8) 
       end hours_for_day
from emp_short
cross join all_days
where total_hours - ((day_num-1) * 8) > 0
```

Comment: Terrific suggestion, you are on the right track for sure. I had to google"cross join" :)  I tried to vote you up but I have no reputation. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Provided that those periods do not overlap for a single employee, you may also try something like this:

```
select  distinct id, "date"-(level-1) "date", least(amount-(level-1)*8, 8) amount
from    sample_data
connect by amount > (level-1)*8
order   by id, "date" desc
```